# How to remove items that exist in the array from object?

Tags: php, arrays

**This is how my array looks like:**

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "600"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "601"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "603"
}
```

**This is how my object looks like:**

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#688 (6) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "601"
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "test8opkpo"
    ["avatar"]=>
    string(85) "http://avatars/user/medium.png"

    ["url"]=>
    string(86) "/index.php"

    ["isOnline"]=>
    int(0)
    ["lastseen"]=>
    string(11) "2 weeks ago"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#689 (6) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "604"
    ["name"]=>
    string(6) "nopita"
    ["avatar"]=>
    string(85) "http://avatars/user/medium.png"

    ["url"]=>
    string(82) "/index.php"
    ["isOnline"]=>
    int(0)
    ["lastseen"]=>
    string(10) "1 week ago"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#690 (6) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "603"
    ["name"]=>
    string(6) "test_b"
    ["avatar"]=>
    string(85) "http://avatars/user/medium.png"

    ["url"]=>
    string(82) "/index.php"
    ["isOnline"]=>
    int(0)
    ["lastseen"]=>
    string(11) "6 hours ago"
  }
```

**Now I want to remove from the object,  each item's id that matches the value inside the array.**

So final output of the object should not contain id's that present in the array given. How to do that?

I tried using `array_diff_key` and `unset` to no avail.

`$contactArray[$i]` represent each id in the object

```
if (in_array($contactArray[$i], $array)) {  
    $a = array_diff_key($results->contacts, [$i => $contactArray[$i]]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created my own set of examples to simulate what you want to happen on your array:

```
$x = array('600','601', '603');
$y = array(
    array("id" => "600",
          "name" => "test",
          "avatar" => "image"
        ),
    array("id" => "601",
          "name" => "test1",
          "avatar" => "image1"
        ),
    array("id" => "602",
          "name" => "test2",
          "avatar" => "image2"
        ),
    array("id" => "603",
          "name" => "test3",
          "avatar" => "image3"
        ),
    array("id" => "604",
          "name" => "test4",
          "avatar" => "image4"
        )
);



echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($y);
echo '</pre>';

$new_arr_ = array();
for($i = 0, $ctr = count($y); $i < $ctr; $i++) {
    if(!in_array($y[$i]["id"], $x)) {
        $new_arr_[] = array($y[$i]["id"], $y[$i]["name"], $y[$i]["avatar"]);
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($new_arr_);
echo '</pre>';
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly the following should work:

```
$contactArray = array_filter($contactArray, function ($v) use ($array) {
      return !in_array(isset($v->id)?$v->id:null, $array);
});
```

Comment: I get this error  syntax error, unexpected ')' on this line: return !in_...... is possible i would like to store the returned object into variable